# Codeigniter error shows in my homepage call to a member function on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started my website developing using the CodeIgniter framework.
My working steps are given below:

```
1. I created a controller named by Home.php 
2. Then I go to the view folder and created a file named by index.php under sub-directory 'home'.
3. When I browse my website it shows me an error
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function view() on null in /home/ontutors/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php on line 18

**Home.php code**

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /**
    * 
    */
    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {

        }       
        function index()
        {
            //echo "Hello welcome";
            $this->load->view('home/index');
        }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Write `parent::__construct();` inside your `__construct()` and check

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter and PHP are you using?

Comment: Thanks.Its working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        /**
        * 
        */
        class Home extends CI_Controller
        {
            function __construct()
            {
               parent::__construct();
            }       
            function index()
            {
                //echo "Hello welcome";
                $this->load->view('home/index');
            }
        }    
    ?>
```

Overwrite your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{       
    function index()
    {
        //echo "Hello welcome";
        $this->load->view('home/index');
    }
}    
 ?>
```